# Identical Zend Navigation code rendering differently on different environments

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

Anyone got ANY idea what could be causing an issue with Zend Navigation. My environments are provisioned through chef and are the same OS etc, same apache setups etc. On my local Ubuntu VM, my webapp renders correctly. The SAME code fails to render the navigation on my TEST VM (on AWS). When I say the same, I've checked and double checked (and is all deployed through PHING), including SCPing the no-displaying-correctly-code off TEST back onto my box, where it then works correctly.

I'm totally stuck. Does anyone know any low level quirks about how Zend renders nav? DOes it write to temp files or something (long shot). The issue is a routing one IMO. The menu doesn't think it is active, yet is using the same routes.ini file as my dev environment, where is it fine.

I've tried changing the environment settings (development, testing) etc but nothing. It can't be the DATA as there is no impact on routing.

Really appreciate any insight..

SOLUTION!

Ahh haaaa. The nav appears to have been broken by a revision of Zend. The reason that was not seen locally, is because I am using Vagrant to manage by VM locally. The mounted folder is , of course, a read-ony filesystem, so my "ln -s -f symlink" to the correct vendor of Zend was silently failing in my script, but working on LIVE on AWS - hence they were using different Zend versions and the new release which breaks my nav (!ANother story) was only seen on Live...! Here end-eth the lesson to self. ALWAYS halt-on-failure in your deployment scripts

Comment: What's the difference? All I see is 'failed to render' in your question. Is there an error? Nice name :)

Comment: Thanks - your name is good too. SOrry - what I mean is that one of my pages fails to render a menu - the other two do. So it seems on one default root URL "/" is not rendering a menu on my AWS env, yet on a different environment with identical code, it does render the menu for "/".

Comment: also, Thats with SCP'd application code to be double sure. All my dependencies are managed through composer (and the same) (including Zend Framework). The only conceivable difference is the fact that TEST uses the "testing" ini block - I've tried to change that to "development" but it still fails on my TEST environment. I've removed all symlinks, recreated, stopped apache a zillion times and nothing.....its maddening

Comment: is it possible you have different base urls? It may help to define the base url for each environment in your application.ini. It also might help if we could see how you are implementing your navigation. Sometimes it's the dumb things that we miss.

Comment: Thanks RockyFord, worth a go for sure

Comment: Thanks all for your help - SOLUTION above...